# Transfer RSSI data from ESP8266 to PC

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to transfer RSSI measurement from ESP8266 to PC and then I will use this measurement in C platform and simple IPS(ındoor Positioning System). 
How can I do this data transfer?
I tried to transfer this data via TCP. But how can i write RSSI value in TCP server? For example the code that is below to write "hello nodeMCU. Can I print RSSI values like this in TCP Server On real time? I mean ESP will get RSSI and then sent to TCP server. Thank you for your help?

```
print(wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION))
print(wifi.sta.config("SSid","password"))
print(wifi.sta.getip())
print('\nAll About Circuits main.lua\n')
tmr.alarm(0, 1000, 1, function()
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then
        print("Connecting to AP...\n")
    else
        ip, nm, gw=wifi.sta.getip()
        print("IP Info: \nIP Address: ",ip)
        print("Netmask: ",nm)
        print("Gateway Addr: ",gw,'\n')
        tmr.stop(0)
    end
end)

-- Start a simple http server
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload)
        print(payload)
        conn:send("Hello, NodeMCU!!! ")
    end)
    conn:on("sent",function(conn) conn:close() end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question is: where is your server? The code you posted starts a server *on the ESP8266*. However, based on your description I understand you want to run the server *on a PC* and send data to it from the device?

There's a potential memory leak (closed upvalues) in the server code you copied from All About Circuits. Try this instead:

```
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive",function(sck,payload)
        print(payload)
        sck:send("Hello, NodeMCU!!! ")
    end)
    conn:on("sent",function(sck) sck:close() end)
end)
```

BUT if the server is on your PC and assuming it's an HTTP server you should use the [NodeMCU HTTP module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/http/#httppost) like so:

- start a new timer
- in each interval read the RSSI
- send an HTTP POST to the server

Here's the code

```
-- replace interval, server address, headers and body of course
tmr.alarm(1, 5000, 1, function()
    local rssi = wifi.sta.getrssi()
    http.post('http://httpbin.org/post',
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n',
        '{"rssi":"'..rssi..'"}',
        function(code, data)
            if (code < 0) then
                print("HTTP request failed")
            else
                print(code, data)
            end
        end)
end)
```